# How to initialize values of Singly Linked List with constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, singly-linked-list

I have to create a constructor that allows a new linked list to be populated with ten consecutive values, starting at 0. Then I need to print the list! So i want to check if the functions I wrote for those are ok. Thanks!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

template <typename E> class SLinkedList;    // forward declaration to be used when declaring SNode

template <typename E>
class SNode {                   
private:
    E elem;                 
    SNode<E> *next;             
    friend class SLinkedList<E>;        
};

template <typename E>
class SLinkedList {             
public:
    SLinkedList();              
    SLinkedList(SNode<E>* v);   //What I need help with
    ~SLinkedList();             
    bool empty() const;         
    E& front();                 
    void printList(SLinkedList<E> &list); //what i need help with
    void addFront(const E& e);      
    void removeFront();         
    int size() const;                   
private:
    SNode<E>* head;             
    int     n;                          // number of items
};

template <typename E>
SLinkedList<E>::SLinkedList()           // constructor
    : head(NULL), n(0) { }

template <typename E>
SLinkedList<E>::SLinkedList(SNode<E>* v){ //WHat I  Need Help With
    SNode<E>* v = new SNode<E>;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        v->elem = i;
}

template <typename E>
bool SLinkedList<E>::empty() const      
{
    return head == NULL; // can also use return (n == 0);
}



template <typename E>
E& SLinkedList<E>::front()      
{
    if (empty()) throw length_error("empty list");
    return head->elem;
}

template <typename E>
SLinkedList<E>::~SLinkedList()          
{
    while (!empty()) removeFront();
}

template<typename E>
void SLinkedList<E>::printList(SLinkedList<E> &list) //What I need help with
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << list << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

template <typename E>
void SLinkedList<E>::addFront(const E& e) { 
    SNode<E>* v = new SNode<E>;     // create new node
    v->elem = e;                // store data
    v->next = head;             // head now follows v
    head = v;               // v is now the head
    n++;
}

template <typename E>
void SLinkedList<E>::removeFront() {        
    if (empty()) throw length_error("empty list");
    SNode<E>* old = head;           
    head = old->next;           
    delete old;             
    n--;
}

template <typename E>
int SLinkedList<E>::size() const {              
    return n;
}
```

thanks in advance for any help or suggestions! It is just these two functions that i am not sure about.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should go to Code Review SE

Comment: Consider a `std::initializer_list` as formal argument type?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo i was trying to look for a specific site for c++ but didnt see it

Comment: I disagree with the prevailing wisdom that this is a job for Code Review as some of the code in question does not work. @jimmbo [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) is a companion site for code that works, but you suspect could work (or at least look) better. My problem with this question is it asks too many questions. Reduce this question to getting help with **one** of your outstanding problems. Ask more questions to resolve other problems as needed. When you have no problems and are looking for help tuning up the code you go to Code Review.

Comment: Step 1) Don't create your own linked list when there already is one, that provides everything you are providing, in the STL, that conforms to standards, and is used by millions of people, unless you are doing so in an academic setting.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz technically none of the list classes in the standard library are required to be implemented with a linked list. They just have to have linked list-like behaviour.

Comment: @user123435456o54343 Sure, but isn't that what one is after? unless they are one of those dummies that is going to implement it themselves, because they think they will get better performance then something put together by committees of people which has been reviewed over a decade. And if they are, then they need to do it in an academic setting.

Comment: I see writing a linked list as a rite of passage for programmers, be it an exercise in school or not. It teaches a number of excellent lessons on pointer use, memory management, visualization and almost certainly debugging. I think it should be learned *after* the standard library rather than before, but the lessons still need to be learned one way or another.

Comment: Which rolls back to a comment targeted at @jimmbo . Visualize the list. Draw the sucker. If you want to add N nodes to the list with a particular order of numbers in it, draw your way through it node by node, connection by connection. Take notes on what you had to do and use the notes as the basis for your code. Once you've done that, you may notice that if you put the sequence into the list *backwards*, you've already done most of the work in the `addFront` method.

Comment: @user4581301 ok good idea! I was thinking it should be somewhat similar tot he addfront function

Comment: @jimmbo see the solution in Remy's answer below because not only is it similar, but you can *use* the `addFront` function and save yourself rewriting a bunch of code. Code that doesn't exist has no bugs. Unless not writing it is the bug, but that's a different problem. Also worth bringing extra attention to the trick he pulls with the double pointer in the commented out code. Work through the code he put in the comments and understand it. Ask a question about it if you need to. It is a very useful concept that can save you a lot of time and code.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you! i will look over his code and check it.

Comment: @user4581301 so say I wanted to creat a list and use that constructor and print the values with printList, how would I go about doing that. (sorry i am barely learning singly linked lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <initializer_list> // C++11 and later only

template <typename E>
class SLinkedList {
public:
    SLinkedList();
    SLinkedList(const E *vals, int num_vals);
    SLinkedList(std::initializer_list<E> vals); // C++11 and later only

    ~SLinkedList();

    bool empty() const;
    int size() const;                   

    E& front();

    void addFront(const E &e);
    void removeFront();

    void printList() const;

private:
    class SNode
    {
    public:
        E elem;
        SNode *next;
        SNode(const E &e, SNode *n = NULL);
    };

    SNode* head;             
    int n; // number of items
};

template <typename E>
SLinkedList<E>::SNode::SNode(const E &e, SLinkedList<E>::SNode *n)
    : elem(e), next(n) { }

template <typename E>
SLinkedList<E>::SLinkedList()
    : head(NULL), n(0) { }

template <typename E>
SLinkedList<E>::SLinkedList(const E *vals, int num_vals)
    : head(NULL), n(0)
{
    for (int i = num_vals-1; i >= 0; --i)
        addFront(vals[i]);

    /* alternatively:
    SNode **ptr = &head;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_vals; ++i)
    {
        *ptr = new SNode(vals[i]);
        ++n;
        ptr = &((*ptr)->next);
    }
    */
}

template <typename E>
SLinkedList<E>::SLinkedList(std::initializer_list<E> vals)
    : head(NULL), n(0)
{
    const E *begin = vals.begin(), *iter = vals.end();
    while (iter != begin)
        addFront(*(--iter));

    /* alternatively:
    const E *iter = vals.begin(), *end = vals.end();
    SNode **ptr = &head;
    while (iter != end)
    {        
        *ptr = new SNode(*iter);
        ++n;
        ptr = &((*ptr)->next);
    }
    */
}

template <typename E>
SLinkedList<E>::~SLinkedList()          
{
    while (head)
        removeFront();
}

template <typename E>
bool SLinkedList<E>::empty() const      
{
    return (!head);
}

template <typename E>
int SLinkedList<E>::size() const
{
    return n;
}

template <typename E>
E& SLinkedList<E>::front()      
{
    if (!head) throw std::length_error("empty list");
    return head->elem;
}

template<typename E>
void SLinkedList<E>::printList() const
{
    SNode *p = head;
    while (p)
    {
        std::cout << p->elem << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename E>
void SLinkedList<E>::addFront(const E& e)
{
    head = new SNode(e, head);
    ++n;
}

template <typename E>
void SLinkedList<E>::removeFront()
{
    SNode* old = head;           
    if (!old) throw std::length_error("empty list");
    head = old->next;           
    --n;
    delete old;             
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/cc3lQQ)